# Crossfire Dual Screen horizontal artifacts

Tags: multiple-monitors, crossfire

With my two 5870s I have a weird problem in crossfire. 
I have two screens a 24''' LCD and a 37'' LED TV.

When in crossfire if I play video on the second screen it gets some odd artifacts of black(ish) horizontal lines across the bottom half of the screen (not seen a problem like it before).  The problem will occur with flash content and VLC, so I think its hardware driver related.

Only solution I've found is to not have the cards in crossfire and plug the TV/Screen into different cards for watching stuff.  My drivers are only a few weeks old now.

Annoying, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a driver problem.  I tried a load of things but I think what worked is probably using Driver Sweeper to remove all GPU stuff then reinstalling a newer driver.

Comment: Hi! Your question wasn't on topic for Gaming, so I migrated it. It lost the checkmark in the progress, however.